# Node js sequential call for 50 times with each request dependent on data of previous request using for loop

Tags: node.js

I want to write code in node js such that it should make 50 sequential api calls where each new api request requires data from previous request

I have tried for loop but failed to pass the previous data in next api call

can you suggest what should i do for efficient code?

Thank you in advance...!!!

Comment: `async-await` is the answer in most of the cases, please share the code you have worked on

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [async / await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) syntax here, this is the most appropriate way of looping over asynchronous calls.

Once we receive the result of each call we can save into an array of all calls.

It is then very straightforward to pass the last call response to the next call.

I've decided to use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) here, since [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) is now deprecated.

Here's an example, I'm using the handy https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com site to test this:

```
const axios = require("axios");

async function callApiRepeatedly(callCount = 1) {

    let callResults = [];
    for (let callIndex = 0; callIndex < callCount; callIndex++) {
        let previousCallResult = (callIndex === 0) ? null: callResults[callResults.length - 1];
        console.log(`Calling api #${callIndex + 1} of ${callCount}...`);
        let callResult = await callApi(callIndex, previousCallResult);
        callResults.push(callResult);   
    }

    console.log("callResults: Returning results array:", callResults);
    return callResults;
}

async function callApi(index, previousCallData) {
    // We can use the previousCallData here if we wish..
    console.log(`CallApi: Call #${index+1}, previous call data:`, previousCallData);
    const url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${index+1}`;
    let response = await axios({ url });
    return response.data
}

// Set this as appropriate, I'm setting to 5 just for test purposes.
// You would be setting to 50 I guess!
const callCount = 5;
callApiRepeatedly(callCount);
```

Comment: Thanks you for your pervious code. I have tried your code, but it's gives following error:- help me (node:17972) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80

Comment: Oh dear, well sorry for that! Are you running it in express or on its own? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, cool. So are you trying to access a local url? The error message you are getting would normally occur when you're accessing port 80 on your local machine. Is the express route set up, e.g. are you hitting the right path and port number? Thanks!

Comment: **This my file and function properly work in my another project. In my this project only occur error**    ((node:8684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80  at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1137:16)
(node:8684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict`

Comment: Which url are you calling with the Axios call? Thanks!

Comment: i Think, Now i find out what is the problem... proxy set time issue (without proxy working fine (and proxy is working in another request)..) 

let options = { 
    url     : 'url',
    proxy   : proxy_cheap,
    headers : { 
        Connection      : 'keep-alive',
        Accept          : '*/*',
    }
};

let response = await axios.request(options);

**Any help how to set proxy in axios ?**

Thanks.!!!

Comment: Ah yes, proxy issues! Have a look at proxy settings in the axios config, https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config. You can set your proxy settings there!

Comment: Yaa Thanks.!!! But without 'https-proxy-agent' **Error Occur** => (node:5720) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: httpsProxyAgent is not defined  

**My config code**
let config = {
    url     : url,
    proxy: {
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 9000,
        auth: {
        username: 'mikeymike',
        password: 'rapunz3l'
        }
    }
};

Comment: No this is not work. without 'https-proxy-agent' package. how can used proxy? or it's possible or not?

Comment: Hmmm.. I'm not an expert in setting up proxies for Axios. You could try https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-https-proxy-fix, which should be compatible and may resolve your issue. You could also give one of the other http client libraries a go, such as node-fetch, superagent or needle.

Comment: No problem at all, glad to be of assistance. I hope you get it working!